# Isomorphism from $U(st) →U(s)\oplus U(t)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, direct-product

> Let $s,t$ are relatively prime then $U(st) $ is isomorphic to $ U(s)\oplus U(t)$.
>
> Define a function from  $U(st) →U(s)\oplus U(t)$ by $x\rightarrow (x $mod $s,x$ mod $t)$.

I proved this is 1-1 and order preserving  But i'm stuck at onto.

Here is my attempt to prove onto:
Since Euler's totient function is multiplicative and $s,t$ are relatively prime , both  $U(st) $ and $ U(s)\oplus U(t)$ has same number of elements.So 1-1 implies the function is onto. I think it is correct

But I'm looking for a straight forward method to prove it is onto using definition of onto.( i.e every element in co domain has pre image)

Def: U(n) is set of all integers relatively prime to n and less than n

Thanks

Comment: I suppose that $U(n)=(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)^\times$ in this context?

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen U(n) is set of all integers relatively prime to n and less than n

Comment: Looks like the chinese remainder theorem will finish your proof.

Comment: @David peterson ,provided i will allow to use it...But I don't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to *use* the Chinese Remainder theorem, but its constructive proof tells you *how* to find the surjection. In fact you will find, if $x\in U(s), y\in U(t)$:

$$(xt\cdot(t^{-1}\text{ mod }s) + ys\cdot(s^{-1}\text{ mod }t)) \text{ mod }st\mapsto (x,y)$$

All that's left is to verify it is the case.

Comment: It's been a few years, but since $(s,t)=1$, $t$ has an inverse (mod s). In this case it would be an arithmetic operation. I believe I got this directly from the proof of the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification sir.I shall delete the comment to avoid confusion.